# Why does the sin_family member exist?

Tags: c, sockets, struct

If I am using the struct sockaddr_in, the address family is already specified in any sockets I create.

Furthermore,it seems redundant to use the sin_family member if it must always be AF_INET.

So why does the sin_family member exist?

Comment: Um... it only has to be `AF_INET` for TCP and UDP connections.  It could be something else, such as `AF_UNIX` (or `AF_LOCAL`) for Unix Domain sockets.  It depends on the kind of underlying network connection you want.

Comment: [Berkeley sockets: Protocol and address families](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_sockets#Protocol_and_address_families)

Comment: But if you are using af_unix wouldn't you use struct sockaddr_un?

Comment: @JohnSzakmeister struct sockaddr_in is used for ipv4, so the address family can never be anything else other than AF_INET

Comment: All of the different sockaddr_xxx structures have an xxx_family field at the beginning and that field specifies which format is used for the rest of the structure. It's kind of like a C `union` but without the need for every compilation to include hundreds or thousands of header files covering all of the possibilities that can occur in the union.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085: It's also poorly designed such that, if you try to use it as such, you invoke undefined behavior. :-( Using `sa_family` safely (and in general, using `sockaddr` family structs safely at all) is very difficult, and generally should be avoided. Use `getnameinfo` and `getaddrinfo` instead and you don't have to.

Comment: What dave_thompson_085 said.  You should view the sockaddr_xxx variants as a giant union.  If you look at functions like `bind()`, they don't take a `struct sockaddr_in *` but a `struct sockaddr *`, which you get by casting a your specific type (`sockaddr_in`) to the generic `sockaddr` type.  As R said, it is fraught with issues.

Comment: @JohnSzakmeister Would it be correct to say that because sockaddr_in is cast to sockaddr, the sa-family property must exist, so that the sockaddr struct is aware of the family of addresses to use?

Comment: Yes, exactly. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's true the `sin_family` member of `struct sockaddr_in` must always be `AF_INET`. The reason for this is so that it's possible to tell the actual type of a generalized socket descriptor.

`struct sockaddr_in` is one of several types of socket address descriptors, with different members depending on the network protocol:

```
struct sockaddr_in {
    sa_family_t    sin_family; /* always AF_INET */
    in_port_t      sin_port;
    struct in_addr sin_addr;
};

struct sockaddr_in6 {
    sa_family_t     sin6_family; /* always AF_INET6 */
    in_port_t       sin6_port;
    uint32_t        sin6_flowinfo;
    struct in6_addr sin6_addr;
    uint32_t        sin6_scope_id;
};

struct sockaddr_un {
    sa_family_t  sun_family; /* always AF_UNIX */
    char         sun_path[108];
};

/* and more ... */
```

Some POSIX functions like `bind` and `accept` take a pointer to `struct sockaddr`, a dummy type that just has the initial `sa_family_t sa_family;` member.  So they, or other code, can deal with any one of those structs cast to a [`const`] `struct sockaddr*` pointer by checking the protocol family, and then casting back to the actual type based on that value.

For example, a logging wrapper around `bind` might do:

```
int loggable_bind(int sockfd, const struct sockaddr* addr, socklen_t addrlen)
{
    bool do_log = logging_enabled();
    if (do_log) {
        switch (addr->sa_family) {
        case AF_INET: {
            const struct sockaddr_in* addr_in = (const struct sockaddr_in*) addr;
            printf("bind: fd=%d family=AF_INET addr=%s port=%u",
                   sockfd,
                   inet_ntoa(addr_in->sin_addr),
                   (unsigned) addr_in->sin_port);
            break;
        }
        case AF_INET6: {
            const struct sockaddr_in6* addr_in6 = (const struct sockaddr_in6*) addr;
            printf("bind: fd=%d family=AF_INET6 addr=%.*s port=%u",
                   sockfd,
                   sizeof(addr_in6->sin6_addr.s6_addr),
                   (const char*) addr_in6->sin6_addr.s6_addr,
                   (unsigned) addr6_in->sin6_port);
            break;
        }
        case AF_UNIX: {
            const struct sockaddr_un* addr_un = (const struct sockaddr_un*) addr;
            if (addrlen == sizeof(sa_family_t)) {
                printf("bind: fd=%d family=AF_UNIX Unnamed");
            } else if (addr_un->sun_path[0] == '\0') {
                printf("bind: fd=%d family=AF_UNIX Abstract, path='");
                for (size_t i=1; i<(addrlen-offsetof(struct sockaddr_un, sun_path)); ++i) {
                    int c = (unsigned char) addr_un->sun_path[i];
                    if (isprint(c))
                        putchar(c);
                    else
                        printf("\\x%02x", (unsigned) c);
                }
                putchar('\'');
            } else {
                printf("bind: fd=%d family=AF_UNIX Named, path=%s",
                       fd, addr_un->sun_path);
            }
            break;
        }
        default:
            printf("bind: fd=%d family=%u", fd, (unsigned) addr->sa_family);
            break;
        }
    }
    int result = bind(fd, addr, addrlen);
    if (do_log) {
        int local_err = errno;
        printf(" -> %d\n", result);
        if (result < 0)
            printf("  errno=%d: %s\n", local_err, strerror(local_err));
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

See the `getsockname` and `getpeername` functions. These may operate on sockets you *inherited* via exec, e.g. from inetd, where since you did no create them you have no a priori knowledge of the address family involved. Having the family be part of the address allows you to determine how to interpret the address.

It also makes it possible to use `getaddrinfo` and `getnameinfo` to write address-family-agnostic code (no hard-coding of IPv4 or v6). With these APIs, `struct sockaddr` and its variants should be treated as entirely opaque types, which carry their own specific type identifier only for use by the interfaces you pass them to. (This is analogous to certain uses of inheritance in C++.)